# Why can't I use #define for keywords in C?

Tags: c++, c, macros, macrodef

I'm trying to use the following code in C++. Can someone tell me why it is showing error?

```
#define  def namespace;
using def std;
int main(){
return 0;
}
```

while the following code is working fine

```
#define  def namespace std;
using def;
int main(){
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to replace standard keywords with your own..?

Comment: @Luc Touraille just trying to get good with the sintax

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is because of the embedded semicolon:

```
#define  def namespace;
                      ^
                      |
                     WHOA!
```

Note that `#define` itself doesn't need a semicolon to terminate the definition, so if you use one it becomes part of the text that will be inserted wherever the macro is used.

After preprocessing, the first example will turn the `using` line into:

```
using namespace; std;
```

which has syntactic problems, obviously.

The fix is to remove the trailing semicolon  in the `#define` line, like so:

```
#define def namespace
```

You should figure out how to read the pre-processed code with your compiler, it's always instructive when straightening out macro-induced confusion.

Comment: Wow. I haven't noticed that.

Comment: @MarkGarcia: When you have trouble with the preprocessor, it's worth seeing if you can invoke it and see its output.  For example, with GNU's gcc you can say something like `gcc -E program.cc | less`.  You'll be able to see if the generated code meets your expectations, and exactly what code the later compilation stages are processing.